# IdentityRole shows an error at the create page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have included the following line to use IdentityRole predefined table which contains Name and ID field.

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>
```

I keep getting a number of errors for not recognizing the model.Name which exists at the class IdentityRole.

The errors that I am getting is:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0411  The type arguments for method 'LabelExtensions.LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>, object)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. 13_Views_Roles_Create.cshtml    C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxxxV2\JobBoardSystem\Views\Roles\Create.cshtml    20  Active



Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0411  The type arguments for method 'ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, string, object)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.  13_Views_Roles_Create.cshtml    C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\JobBoardSystem V2\xxxx\Views\Roles\Create.cshtml  23  Active
```

The code is the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 

{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>RoleViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

        @section Scripts {
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The create page usually doesn't deal with a list, just with a single model item. Your model should be

```cs
@model Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole
```